# varimp (R partykit) retuns errors for conditional importance setting

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection, party

Firstly, I constructed a model by

```
cf1 <- cforest(y~., data = DATA, strata = DATA$y,
           ntree = 200L, mtry = 10)
```

Here considering the dataset is very imbalanced (`y=1` takes 7% of the whole observations), so I add `strata` here to make sure observations with `y=1` are not ignored in bagging. `cf1` works normally, in terms of the confusion matrix. However, when I tried to implement feature selection by

```
cf1.imp_cond <- varimp(cf1, conditional = TRUE)
```

It returns

```
Error in x[strata == s] <- .resample(x[strata == s]) : 
NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

I can't figure out what does this error mean. Someone met this before?

----update

Here is an manipulated [test data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HQIZ6NWja_FUI9bi618-qhCLJHt3IbHs) from the original dataset I am using. Here is the code

```
cf2 <- cforest(X5_years_survival~., data = test, strata = X5_years_survival,
           ntree = 200L, mtry = 6)
cf2.imp_cond <- varimp(cf2, conditional = TRUE)
```

Still, I have the error:

```
Error in x[strata == s] <- .resample(x[strata == s]) : 
NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

---update

The error occurs when `kidids_node` function is applied.

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example? Otherwise it's hard to debug.

Comment: @AchimZeileis I am trying to do so. By the way, do you think my way in setting `strata` is the way it supposed to be?

Comment: @AchimZeileis example added.

Comment: Thanks. However, this runs successfully for me after doing `test <- read.csv("test.csv")`. It does not seem to matter whether `X5_years_survival` is turned into a `factor` (as requested by `cforest`) or not. When working on an improved example: try to install the latest version of the package and boil down the example even more (e.g., one covariate and one strata) to reliably and quickly produce an error.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Do you mean you didn't meet the same error? I installed 1.2.1 version of `partykit`.

Comment: Yes. For me everything runs without error.

Comment: It is as you described. But then `X5_years_survival` is treated as an integer variable, and so `cforest` is a regression model, instead of a classfier, right? So that means, for classfication proble, we need to construct it as a regression model first and then we can use `varimp` to calculate the conditional variable importance, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171725/discussion-between-bs-he-and-achim-zeileis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is, if I keep all `integer` type covariate, instead of converting them by `as.factor`, applying `varimp` makes no error.